# Dependency error in vue project with vue-material

Tags: npm, compiler-errors, vuejs2, vue-material

I'm developping a vue application. everything was good until I replace my static store with a Vuex store.

When I make a npm run dev, I got this error:

```
These dependencies were not found:
* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!sass-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./App.vue in ./src/App.vue
* vue-material in ./src/main.js
* vue-material/dist/theme/default-dark.css in ./src/main.js
* vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css in ./src/main.js, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/StepperMotor.vue
```

I d'ont understand the content of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install those Dependencies

```
npm i --save vue-style-loader . 
npm i --save css-loader
```

and while installing if there is permission error then give read and write permission to your `node_modules` folder